How to Map XML values from a database using Hibernate?
Im using Hibernate to get information form an Oracle DB and  im getting stuck because one of the columns is used to store xml files.
I need a way to get those files in a way where I can actually read whats inside them as right now im getting a "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2009" Error.
Im using annotations for this, is there a way to map what is on the xmls or to receive it as a String?
The columns in sql have a XMLTYPE as their column type.
This is my Class with annotations:
@Entity
@Table(name="table")
@Data
public class defaultFileMeta {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "fmi")

    private long fMI;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long Id;
    @Column(name = "CREATION_TIME")
    private String cTime;
    @Column(name = "RECO_TIME")
    private String rTime;
    @Column(name = "FILEATT")
    private String fileAt;

    public defaultFileMeta(){
        super();
    }


}

And this is my main:


public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            initConnectionPool();

        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(defaultFileMeta.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        SQLQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(<query>);
            List<Object[]> rows = query.list();

            for(Object[] row : rows){
               
                for (int i = 0; i < row.length ; i++)
                    System.out.print(row[i].toString() + " | ");
              
            }

        session.close();

        }catch (SQLException | UniversalConnectionPoolException failedToConnect){
            logger.error("Failed to initialize connection pool at constructor: {}", failedToConnect.getMessage());
            throw new FailedDBConnectionException("Cannot connect to DB.",failedToConnect);
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }

I tried using the annotations for @Lob and add the columnDefinition="XMLTYPE" to the @column, but it has not worked.
